# How can I convert this SQL to VB.NET LINQ

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I am having some real trouble converting this statement from SQL to LINQ.

```
DECLARE @radians float
SELECT @radians = 57.295779513082323 
SELECT 
    t1.*, 
    DistanceInMiles = 
        3963.0*acos(
            sin(t1.Latitude/(@radians))
            * sin(t2.Latitude/(57.295779513082323))
            + cos(t1.Latitude/(@radians))
            * cos(t2.Latitude/(@radians)) 
            * cos(t2.Longitude/(@radians) - t1.Longitude/(@radians))
        )
FROM ZipCodeData t1
JOIN ZipCodeData t2 ON (
    3963.0*acos(
        sin(t1.Latitude/(@radians)) 
        * sin(t2.Latitude/(57.295779513082323)) 
        + cos(t1.Latitude/(@radians)) 
        * cos(t2.Latitude/(@radians)) 
        * cos(t2.Longitude/(@radians) 
        - t1.Longitude/(@radians))
    ) < 100
)
WHERE t2.ZipCode='10001'
ORDER BY DistanceInMiles
```

I am working in VB.NET

I don't have any idea where to start

```
Dim results = z1 in Entities.ZipCodeDatas
```

Ok so I have a start, but seriously

EDIT:

```
Dim radians = 57.29577951309232
Dim results = From z1 In Entities.ZipCodeDatas
              z1.ZipCode
              Join z2 In Entities.ZipCodeDatas On z2.ZipCode Equals z1.ZipCode
```

First, I don't know how to create `DistanceInMiles` and I don't know how to create this second Join and I don't know how to Join tables with a Less than `<` clause

Edit 2:

```
Dim result = (
    From z1 In Entities.ZipCodeDatas
    Join z2 In Entities.ZipCodeDatas On z2.ZipCode Equals z1.ZipCode
    Where (
        3963.0 * Math.Acos(
            Math.Sin(z1.Latitude.Value / (radians)) _
            * Math.Sin(z2.Latitude.Value / (57.295779513082323)) _
            + Math.Cos(z1.Latitude.Value / (radians)) _
            * Math.Cos(z2.Latitude.Value / (radians)) _
            * Math.Cos(z2.Longitude.Value / (radians) - z1.Longitude.Value / (radians)) _
        )
    ) < radius
)
```

Comment: Don't forget you have the option to convert the above into a stored proc and then call the proc using EF.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
Dim radians = 57.295779513082323
Dim result = ( _
    From t1 in Entities.ZipCodeDatas
    From t2 in Entities.ZipCodeDatas
    Where t2.ZipCode = "10001" _
    And 3963.0 * SqlFunctions.Acos( _
        SqlFunctions.Sin(t1.Latitude / (radians)) _
        * SqlFunctions.Sin(t2.Latitude/(57.295779513082323)) _
        + SqlFunctions.Cos(t1.Latitude/(radians)) _
        * SqlFunctions.Cos(t2.Latitude/(radians)) _
        * SqlFunctions.Cos(t2.Longitude/(radians) - t1.Longitude/(radians)) _
    ) < 100
    Select New With { _
        ZipCodeDatas = t1, _
        DistanceInMiles = 3963.0 * SqlFunctions.Acos( _
            SqlFunctions.Sin(t1.Latitude/(@radians)) _
            * SqlFunctions.Sin(t2.Latitude/(57.295779513082323)) _
            + SqlFunctions.Cos(t1.Latitude/(@radians)) _
            * SqlFunctions.Cos(t2.Latitude/(@radians)) _
            * SqlFunctions.Cos(t2.Longitude/(@radians) - t1.Longitude/(@radians)) _
        )
    }
).OrderBy(o => o.DistanceInMiles)
```

Comment: I will have to edit this some -- you're vb is rusty :)

Comment: I will not be able to Join like that -- `Equals` is expected

Comment: I'm wondering why you're joining anyway, wouldn't it work without the t2 join? The `< 100` should maybe be added to the `where` clause instead.

Comment: I am comparing different values from the same table in order to find entries that fit the requirement of having the ZipCode I pass in and also being within a given radius (here it is 100 miles) of the original zipcode

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I have an idea, which may or may not work... will make an edit in a bit. :)